# Render target not found using dedicated Graphics card

Tags: c++, direct3d11

I'm building a simulator using Direct3D 11. Recently I upgraded to VS2015 from VS2013. I also switched to Win10 and I've had a lot of problem porting the project.

This last one I can't seem to solve:

**When I run the program with the dedicated graphics card, it seems like the shaders can't find the target draw-surface (Although I get no Error Messages)**

The Window to be drawn to is simply just white. It doesn't even Clear in the right color. I've also tried enabling "Force WARP".

My dedicated card is a GeForce GTX 770M. 
My integrated graphics accelerator is on the Intel i7-4800MQ

I could technically keep working using the integrated HAL. It just bugs me. Get it?

My Pixel Shader looks like this, if it's of interest. It simply passes the Color transformed to pixel-space:

```
struct PS_OUTPUT
{
    //float4 position;
    float4 color;
};

PS_OUTPUT PS_Main(float4 color : COLOR, float4 position : SV_Position0 ) : SV_TARGET
{
    PS_OUTPUT output;


    output.color = color ;



    return output;
```

}

The DGC uses driver version 368.81. I can't seem to find anyone who has similar problems with this.

Any Ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have the debug device enabled? With Windows 10, you have to enable the _Graphics Tools_ Windows optional feature to enable it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't find the path you speak of. Via VS15 I enabled debugging through Debug -> Graphics -> DirectX Control Panel and set my program to use graphical debugging. No messages are muted and it's set to display all messages!    I also looked for the path you mentioned in windows Settings, but I have no "Optional Features" tab.

Comment: Be aware this program is using Win32 and WINAPI. I know it's kinda outdated.

Comment: PC Settings -> System -> Apps & features -> Manage optional features -> Add a feature

Comment: Thank you for being parental with me. On my system, there's no choice called _Graphics Tools_ in _Add A Feature_.  Might this mean that it's already enabled?

Comment: Actually, the _Graphics Tools_ is listed in the _Manage Optional Features_ tab.